# How to send a signal to a child several times avoiding zombie state? C language

Tags: c, signals, fork, kill, zombie-process

I need to send a signal to a child process 3 times.

The problem is that the child only receives the signal once and then transforms into a zombie.

The expected output would be:

I'm the child 11385 and i received SIGUSR1

I'm the child 11385 and i received SIGUSR1

I'm the child 11385 and i received SIGUSR1

But the real output is:

I'm the child 11385 and i received SIGUSR1

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void my_handler()
{
  printf("\n I'm the child %i and i received SIGUSR1\n", getpid());
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int *array;
    int N = 10;
    int i;
    pid_t pid1;
    array=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);


    signal(SIGUSR1,my_handler);

    for (i = 0; i< N; i++) 
    {
        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1 < 0)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid1 > 0)
        {
            array[i]= pid1;
        }

        else
        {   
            sleep(100);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    i=0;
    while(i<3) // I need to call the son 3 times
    {
        kill(array[1], SIGUSR1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void my_handler()` -->> `void my_handler(int signum)` [With the wrong signature, the return from the signal handler effectively kills your child] And also: you should not call printf() from inside a signal handler.

Comment: @wildplasser The code is an example for a specific signal, so it has no argument.

The printf is also an example and is not the real problem :/

Comment: But it is **called** with an argument, which disrupts the stack (on return)

Comment: @wildplasser So how to prevent them from dying? :(

Comment: By changing the function signature!

Comment: @wildplasser i don't understand :(

Comment: Run the program with one child, and attach gdb to the child. (you should probably add some sleep to allow you to start gdb in an other terminal and attach ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the child receives the signal, it is probably waiting for the `sleep` to terminate. The first signal will interrupt the `sleep` even if the time hasn't expired, causing it to return with `errno` set to `EINTR`. If you want it to keep sleeping, you need to call `sleep` again.

Comment: I added a sleep and shows the message twice, if I add 4 it shows 4 times. How do I do for N sleeps ?.

Anyway, those sleep prevent me from killing the process so the SIGTERM signal does not work.

Comment: Put the sleep in a loop. Your SIGTERM handler should set a global variable which indicates that the loop should terminate. (The variable should be volatile)

Comment: Or check the return value of sleep.  It returns a value for a reason.   In fact, pretty much for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

- your parent process exited without wait()ing for the child
- The signals could be sent to fast, I added a short delay
- i added more delays
- the correct signature for a signal handler is `void handler(int signum)` This is crucial, because the handler is called with an argument, and the stack layout is different for signal handlers.
- you should not call printf() from a signal handler, it is not async safe.

---

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char pidstr[10];
char massage[]="        I'm the child and i received SIGUSR1\n";

#define CNT 1
void my_handler(int signum)
{
write(0, massage, strlen(massage));
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int i , err, status;
    pid_t pid1;
    int array[CNT];

    signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);

    for (i = 0; i< CNT; i++) {
        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1 < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        else if (pid1 > 0) {
                printf("ChildPid=%d\n", pid1 );
            array[i]= pid1;
        }

        else
        {   // child
                // signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
            sprintf(pidstr,"[%d]", getpid() );
            memcpy (massage,pidstr, strlen(pidstr));
            sleep(10);
                printf("Unslept\n");
            sleep(10);
                printf("Unslept\n");
            sleep(10);
                printf("Unslept\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    sleep(10);
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        err = kill(array[0], SIGUSR1);
        printf("Err=%d:%d\n", err, (err) ? errno: 0 );
        sleep(1);
    }

    while ( (pid1=wait( &status)) != -1){
        printf("[Parent] Reaped %d\n", pid1);
        }

return 0;
}
```